# ask for making divs draggable and not placed off the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, draggable

I had a hard time coding, so I asked a question here.

If you press the button on the upper left, you can make the color boxes invisible. At the same time, I wrote down the code the the button can make the color boxes could be placed in a random location.

I would like to make sure that the color boxes do not go out of the screen. Even if the width and height were set to 100% on the body, the color box was placed off the screen.

And I want to correct the color boxes so that they can be moved by draggable function, but they don't work together. I would also like to ask for help with this.

and I am not a coding expert man so, I need a comment with coding example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    
    <style type="text/css">
    body {margin:0; padding:0;}
    button {position: absolute; width: 30px; height: 30px; background: #edd6bc;}
    .random {position: absolute; width: 30px; height: 30px;}

    </style>

    <script>

    </script>

</head>


<body >

    <button onclick="showhide()" value="Zeige Features" id="button"></button>

    <div style="display: none; background: #6d97b4;" class="random" ></div>
    
    <div style="display: none; background: #c9656f;" class="random" ></div>
    
    <div style="display: none; background: #f1eb40;" class="random" ></div>
    
    <div style="display: none; background: #00825c;" class="random" ></div>
    
    <div style="display: none; background: #009ce0;" class="random" ></div>
    
    <div style="display: none; background: #cee4a6;" class="random" ></div>



<script type="text/javascript">
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
const width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".random");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  Array.from(boxes).forEach(box => {
    box.style.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1) + "px";
    box.style.right = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1) + "px";
  })
});

function showhide() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".random");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].style.display === "block") {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x[i].style.display =
        "block";
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an explanation tell me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    
    <style type="text/css">
    body {margin:0; padding:0;}
    button {position: absolute; width: 30px; height: 30px; background: #edd6bc;}
    .random {position: absolute; width: 30px; height: 30px;}

    </style>

    <script>

    </script>

</head>


<body >

    <button onclick="showhide()" value="Zeige Features" id="button"></button>

    <div style="display: none; background: #6d97b4;" class="random"></div>
    
    <div style="display: none; background: #c9656f;" class="random"></div>
    
    <div style="display: none; background: #f1eb40;" class="random"></div>
    
    <div style="display: none; background: #00825c;" class="random"></div>
    
    <div style="display: none; background: #009ce0;" class="random"></div>
    
    <div style="display: none; background: #cee4a6;" class="random"></div>



<script type="text/javascript">
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const height = document.documentElement.clientHeight - 30;
const width = document.documentElement.clientWidth - 30;
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".random");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  Array.from(boxes).forEach(box => {
    box.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * height) + "px";
    box.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * width) + "px";
  })
});

function showhide() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".random");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].style.display === "block") {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x[i].style.display =
        "block";
    }
  }
}




function mouseDown(downEvent) {
  var box = downEvent.srcElement;
  var offX = box.getBoundingClientRect().left - downEvent.x;
  var offY = box.getBoundingClientRect().top - downEvent.y;
  document.onmousemove = e => {
    box.style.top = Math.min(Math.max(e.y + offY, 0), height) + "px";
    box.style.left = Math.min(Math.max(e.x + offX, 0), width) + "px";
  }
  document.onmouseup = e => {
    document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
  }
  return false;
}

Array.from(boxes).forEach(box => {
  box.onmousedown = mouseDown;
})

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

While generating the `top` * `right` subtract the height and width of the div

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
const width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".random");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  Array.from(boxes).forEach(box => {
    const top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (height - 30) + 1) + "px";
    const right = Math.floor(Math.random() * (width - 30) + 1) + "px";

    box.style.top = top;
    box.style.right = right;
  })
});

function showhide() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".random");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].style.display === "block") {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x[i].style.display =
        "block";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #edd6bc;
}

.random {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showhide()" value="Zeige Features" id="button"></button>

<div style="display: none; background: #6d97b4;" class="random"></div>

<div style="display: none; background: #c9656f;" class="random"></div>

<div style="display: none; background: #f1eb40;" class="random"></div>

<div style="display: none; background: #00825c;" class="random"></div>

<div style="display: none; background: #009ce0;" class="random"></div>

<div style="display: none; background: #cee4a6;" class="random"></div>
```

Comment: I still don't understand about meaning of 
    
const top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (height - 30) + 1) + "px"; 
const right = Math.floor(Math.random() * (width - 30) + 1) + "px";

what is this code meaning can you explain here ?

Comment: You can also write `box.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (height - 30) + 1) + "px"`. The code there was just creating variable before assigning

Comment: ah ha I get it. thanks. then what code that you wrote is making color boxes places in the screen?

Comment: These two `(height - 30) + 1)` & `(width - 30)`

Comment: I'm so sorry that I've been asking questions over and over again. One or two color boxes are still having problems placing them off the screen. I certainly did not understand the change with the numbers 30 and 1. -> (height - 30) + 1)